# ID.Replace not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, replace

I have a gridview where when I click on the row I need to get the ID of that row.

So I created the click function which returns an ID like `gvBookingsRow_5`

```
$(".gvBookingsRow_").click(function (e) {
   ShowBookingComment($(this).attr("ID"));                                                                
});
```

So then in my function I need to separate the `gvBookingsRow_` from the `5`:

```
function ShowBookingComment(ID){
    PageMethods.GetBookingComment(ID.replace("gvBookingsRow_",""),OnGetBookingComment,null);
  }
```

I tried using `ID.replace` but it is still returning the ID `gvBookingsRow_5`. I just want it to return the number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try assigning your `ID` with the replaced string like

Edit: Replace `ID` with `id`

```
$(".gvBookingsRow_").click(function (e) {
   ShowBookingComment($(this).attr("id"));                                                                
});

function ShowBookingComment(ID){
    ID = ID.replace("gvBookingsRow_","");
    PageMethods.GetBookingComment(ID, OnGetBookingComment,null);
}
```

Comment: Tried this and it still returns the ID as `gvBookingsRow_5`

Comment: I updated my answer. What do you get when you replace `attr("ID")` with `attr('id')`?